# Django issue altering get_queryset in Class Based View with POST data

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-class-based-views, http-status-code-414

Not really sure how I can't figure this out but I am trying to POST a form to alter the contents of `get_queryset()` but it isn't keeping the filtered items, it calls `get_queryset` multiple times during a `POST` for a form and loses the POST filtering as it calls `GET` too. I must be doing something wrong as this should be easy. I can only seem to alter the queryset with `GET` variables, how do I port this to work with post, can  someone please help point me somewhere?

I'm using `GET` variables to alter the filtering now (which is somewhat fine with edits I made earlier to shorten the string), but I need to use `POST` for better efficiency as my form posts over 400 items in a multiple choice field so the URL gets really long and has chances for browser failure, and causing HTTP 414 Errors due to the data URL being too long.

**This is my example trying to filter with `POST`**

```
class GeneralLedgerDatatableView(DatatableView):
    model = GeneralLedger
    datatable_class = GeneralLedgerDatatable
    template_name = 'accounting/general_ledger/general_ledger_list.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

        context = self.get_context_data()

        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        title = 'General Ledger: Transaction Detail'

        context['title'] = title
        properties = Property.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('name')
        accounts = GLAccount.objects.all().order_by('sortable_account_identifier')

        current_property = self.request.session.get('property')
        if current_property:
            current_property = current_property.pk


        form = SelectFilterOptionsForm(self.request.POST or None, properties=properties, accounts=accounts, initial={
            'from_date': timezone.now().replace(day=1, month=1).strftime('%m/%d%/%Y'),
            'accounts': [x.pk for x in accounts],
            'to_date': timezone.now().strftime('%m/%d%/%Y'),
            'property': current_property
        })

        context['form'] = form

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()

        if self.request.POST:
            # THIS IS CALLED BUT SO IS GET AND ALL ARE RETURNED?
            property = self.request.POST.get('property')
            accounts = [x for x in self.request.POST.getlist('accounts') if x]
            from_date = self.request.POST.get('from_date')
            to_date = self.request.POST.get('to_date')

            q_items = list()
            if property:
                # filter_dict['journal_line_item__property__pk__in'] = properties
                q_items.append(Q(
                    property=property,
                ))

                q_items.append(Q(
                    account__pk__in=accounts,
                ))
                q_items.append(
                    Q(
                        date_entered__date__gte=datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
                        date_entered__date__lte=datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
                    )
                )

            queryset = queryset.select_related(
                'transaction_code',
                'book',
                'account',
                'property'
            ).filter(*q_items)


        return queryset
```